# Logging errors by serilog-timings at loglevel "Error"

Tags: c#, serilog

I show my idea on the serilog-timing example.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .WriteTo.LiterateConsole()
        .WriteTo.Seq("http://localhost:5341")
        .CreateLogger();

    Log.Information("Hello, world!");

    var count = 10000;
    using (var op = Operation.Begin("Adding {Count} successive integers", count))
    {
        try
        {
            var sum = Enumerable.Range(0, count).Sum();
            Log.Information("This event is tagged with an operation id");

            var x= 0;
            var y = 1/x;
            op.Complete("Sum", sum);
        }
        catch(System.Exception ex)
        {
            op.Abandon(ex, LogEventLevel.Error);
        }
        Log.Information("Goodbye!");
    }


    Log.CloseAndFlush();
}
```

Unfortunately, the `op.Abandon()` method currently doesn't have the second parameter which would set the log level. It creates always a Warning-level log item. I can make the modification in serilog-timing (adding a 2-parameter override of `op.Abandon()`) but perhaps there is also a workaround for this issue, like in the case of our [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71975231/4924819). So, my question is, can I achieve the desired result without this modification, or this time, I can't avoid making the necessary changes in the serilog-timing project?